# setting variables against data retrieved from a database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am building a simple security system using java (eclipse) and I am using the MYSQL statement to pull data from the database

```
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select name, username, password from securitysystem.employee where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'");
```

but what if i wanted to create a variable **user= name**, how would I do that? name is referring to the name retrieved using the statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never put your parameter right into a query string. 
Instead, do this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select name, username, password "+
  "from securitysystem.employee where username = ? and password = ?");
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, password);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

To get the results, do this:

```
if (rs.next()) {                  //move to 1st result row
  String name = rs.getString(1);  //first result column
  String user = rs.getString(2);  //second result column
  //  ..etc
}
```

Comment: Surely you meant `while` and not `if`, unless you only want the first row ;)

Comment: I'm assuming that the statement is only designed to return one row, because it takes a username and password.

Comment: yes it only returns 1 row because it will have to match the username and password :) thanks this answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    String user = rs.getString("name");
}
```